# Django log level - only WARNING up collected - no INFO

Tags: python, django, logging, python-logging

I am runing Django apllication and trying to collect logs from it. I am trying to collect everything from INFO up however in the log file I have only WARNING up.

I have replicated settings.py to a basic test Django site where my logging works as inteneded with INFO collected.
The problem must be related to the configuration of my Django app.

Could you point me please in to any avenue for troubleshooting please.

The following variables are collected from the .env file - LOG_MAX_SIZE, LOG_NUMBER_OF_FILES, LOG_LOCATION, LOG_LEVEL.

```
#LOGGING SETTINGS
LOG_MAX_SIZE = 52428800 #max size of single log file in bytes
LOG_NUMBER_OF_FILES = 5 #number of old log files
LOG_LOCATION = 'logs/rotatingLog.log' #default name and location of a log file
LOG_LEVEL = 'INFO' #Log level to be collected through all django loggers - options include: DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR, CRITICAL
```

settings.py file extract:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,  # the dictConfig format version
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,  # retain the default loggers

    'handlers': {
       'rotatingFile': {
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'maxBytes': LOG_MAX_SIZE,
            'backupCount': LOG_NUMBER_OF_FILES,
            'filename': LOG_LOCATION,
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['rotatingFile'],
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
        },
        'root': {
            'handlers': ['rotatingFile'],
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
        },
        'main': {
            'handlers': ['rotatingFile'],
            'propagate': False,
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
        },
        'application': {
            'handlers': ['rotatingFile'],
            'propagate': False,
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
        },
        'customer': {
            'handlers': ['rotatingFile'],
            'propagate': False,
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
        },
        'chat': {
            'handlers': ['rotatingFile'],
            'propagate': False,
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['rotatingFile'],
            'propagate': False,
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
        },
        'django.security.*': {
            'handlers': ['rotatingFile'],
            'propagate': False,
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
        },
    },
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '{asctime} {levelname} {name} {module} {process:d} {thread:d} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
    },
```

When I start Django app and made a few requests to the URL I am not getting any INFO logs recorded - only WARNING or ERROR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of investigation, I have noted that it may be intended behaviour by Django. Logging works when I am in development mode and using the development server. However, when I switch to Gunnicron, I only get logs with a status >400. Unfortunately, Django documentation does not mention this behaviour.
So instead, in the production, I am calling Gunnicorn like this, and I am getting all status logs:

```
gunicorn -w 4 PressRiver.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --error-logfile /logs/gunicorn-error.log --access-logfile /logs/gunicorn-access.log
```

I think that the ticket below may explain it further.
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/33897